# SQL запрос для каждой группы

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть 2 таблицы: Группы и музыканты.
Необходимо вывести название групп и количество музыкантов в каждой из них

Структура таблиц:

```
groups (id_group, title)
artist(id_artist,id_group,name)
```

Как написать этот запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(a.id_artist), b.title FROM artist a LEFT JOIN groups b ON a.id_group = b.id_group GROUP BY a.id_group;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), `id_group` FROM `artist` GROUP BY `id_group`;
```

Как-то так...